# Get server-relative URL from SP.Web

Tags: sharepoint-server, spweb

I'm trying to retrieve a relative url from a SP.Web
I get my sp.web from a SP.list with

```
SPWeb test = listNL.ParentWeb;
```

When I try to get the url I got an exception:

> test.ServerRelativeUrl' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException

```
test.ServerRelativeUrl;
```

Do you know a solution to retrieve the relative url from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs since `ServerRelativeUrl` property of Web object has not been loaded.

You have to explicitly specify to load `ServerRelativeUrl` property:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list,l => l.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
var webUrl = list.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
```

or use List `ParentWebUrl` property:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
var webUrl = list.ParentWebUrl;
```

to retrieve Web `ServerRelativeUrl` property.

### How to retrieve List server-relative Url via CSOM

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list,l => l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
var listUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
```

Comment: Thanks for yor reply but do you have a solution to test if list.getybytitle exist. I test if it's not null but it's never null as it doesn't exist